# Explain the acceptable English sentence relating to focal or tacit knowledge

Tags: grammar

Compare these two: Explain the acceptable English sentence relating to focal or tacit knowledge.
1. They went for Dinner. 
2. They gone for dinner.

Comment: The distinction is that the second is not standard English. It might be accepted in AAE (which I don't speak)...is that what you're asking about?

Comment: I am not from AAE either! anyway, this question is to explain how tacit knowledge is applied in the instance, we read these 2 sentences.

Comment: What two questions? Even interpreting the 2nd as AAE, I see two declarative sentences, not questions.

Comment: Yes, my Bad!! "sentences"

Comment: I think the second one should be, "They **have** gone for dinner."

Comment: Thanks, Nicholas; I guess your explanation is based on focal knowledge. Thank you..

Comment: "They went for dinner" would have to be at a specific time: "They went for dinner at 6:00PM." Whereas "They have gone for dinner" has no specific time: "They have already gone for dinner."

Comment: You're welcome. Well, I am guessing focal knowledge is focusing on the specific time "they left for dinner" whereas tacit knowledge would be that we know "they have left for dinner", but we don't know when.

Comment: Here are some better examples: "The boy did his homework last night." "The boy has done his homework." / "The boy was sick yesterday." "The boy has been sick."

Comment: Thanks again for the examples; I just joined Stack Exchange & am grateful for Great supportive contributors like your good self Nicholas. God bless.

Comment: You're welcome. I was just guessing because "tacit" means "understood, but not necessarily stated", so I assumed that was what you had meant in your request. It is tacit that "They have gone to dinner" whereas there is focus on when in "They went for dinner at 5pm."

Comment: It's a common error in English even among native speakers. When I was a child, my mother would always write notes to me and leave them on the table. The notes would say something like, "**Went** to the store and will be back in a few hours." Her notes were incorrect grammatically because she had used **went** in them when they should have read, "**Gone** to the store and will be back in a few hours." **Gone** is correct herein because her going to the store had happened at an undisclosed or unknown time in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The past tense is usually used to describe a specific time in the past:

> They *went* for dinner around 5 o'clock this evening.
>
> The children *went* outside to play an hour ago.

The present perfect is used to describe something that has occurred in the past, but whose time is unknown or unimportant:

> They *have already gone* for dinner.
>
> The children *have gone* out to play (at some unknown / unimportant
>   time) and won't be back till 3 o'clock this afternoon.